# Creating Event in MySQL does not work

Tags: mysql, sql

I am creating an event (like crone job) in MySQL to execute a query every 3 seconds but does not work. I tried my best. Here is my code please see if I am doing anything wrong

```
CREATE EVENT `croneJob` 
ON SCHEDULE EVERY 3 SECOND 
STARTS '2014-03-24 13:45:57' 
ON COMPLETION PRESERVE ENABLE 
DO 
insert into ranktable values (1,2,3);
```

It successfully creates it but does not execute every 3 seconds

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to start your MySQL server events scheduler:

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

Loot at:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html

Answer (score 2):

As I know all events are executed by a special event scheduler thread.When we refer to the Event Scheduler, we actually refer to this thread.There is global `event_scheduler` system variable determines whether the Event Scheduler is enabled and running on the server.

Try to set the event_Scheduler on your command line.

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

OR

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = 1;
```

Read more about [events](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/events-configuration.html).

Hope it will help you.

Answer (score 0):

Even setting

```
SET GLOBAL event_scheduler = ON;
```

was not working so I put these lines in **my.ini**

```
[mysqld]
event_scheduler = ON
```

and is working great now.